# Finding what is specifically wrong with resolution on TV-as-monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, colors, tv

Apart from my regular monitor ([Acer GN246HL](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824009642)), I'm using a little TV ([Memorex MLT1931](http://equipboard.com/items/memorex-mlt1931-19-lcd-television)) as a second monitor (through HDMI -- my graphics card is an AMD Radeon 7800 series -- device manager/radeon setting won't tell me which, exactly), and it seems almost impossible to tweak the color/display settings to be just right, on both native resolution (1280x720) or 1980x1080.

If this isn't just "collateral damage" from using a TV instead of a proper monitor, it's very frustrating (and even more so, since I am color-deficient myself).

I apologize that these are photos of LCD screens, but is it possible to tell from these photos which settings (brightness, contrast, gamma, sharpness, colors, etc) specifically are too strong/weak? I tried finding a screenshot to take that included a face, text, and colors that were mismatching (blue at the top)

Actual computer monitor:

[image: Actual computer monitor]

TV monitor (want this one to match the one above):

[image: TV monitor]

Comment: Have you tried changing the Brightness and Contrast on the TV? I would say you need to decrease them both. If possible try decreasing the strength of the blue, compared to the other colors, as well. Also, some TV's have a set of predefined profiles you can pick from, if you have that option I would try out all the profiles before messing with the individual settings.

Comment: I have tried messing with most settings individually, and that's why I decided to make a post - every tweak seemed to make it worse